# How to set a variable from inside a for loop that can be accessed from outside the for loop [Jinja]

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, jinja2

When a user clicks a link, I want Jinja to set a variable called `{{ contact_clicked }}` that is equal to `{{ contact }}`.

I could do `<a href="/?{% contact_clicked = contact %}">.....</a>`. However, that variable is then inaccessible outside of the for loop.

I tried creating a list and then appending a variable to the list and then accessing the first variable in the list. However, the list doesn't wipe when the page reloads (or at any other time) so the variable is set forever.

**EDIT 1:**
My for loop looks like this:

```
    {% set contact_clicked = "" %}

    {% for contact in contact_list %}
        {% if contact in fake_list %}
            <h4 style="color: rgb(200,100,100)"> {{ contact }} NO SUCH ACCOUNT </h4>
        {% else %}
            <a href="/?{% contact_clicked = contact %}"> <h4 style="color: rgb(200,200,200)"> {{ contact }} </h4> </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I'm talking about a **Jinja2** for loop, **not a Python for loop**.

Comment: You mention a for loop, but don't show it. Please add more code so we can see some context.

Comment: From your description and how I'm used to using jinja2 or similar, I'm not sure you're thinking about this the right way.  I'm used to having Jinja2 generate an HTML page on the server (running Flash, Django, or another web framework) which is passed to the client... unless you want to do a whole page refresh, the client clicks need to be handled by javascript.  Could you clarify how your environment is setup, and include some more html/etc. for context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** Read on to see how...
To set a variable, I told Jinja to direct me to **/contact_msg/{{ contact }}**. Let's say I clicked on a contact called 'bob'. I would be directed to **/contact_msg/bob**. The code is below

```
{% for contact in contact_list %}
    {% if contact in fake_list %}
        <h4 style="color: rgb(200,100,100)"> {{ contact }} NO SUCH ACCOUNT </h4>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/contact_msg/{{ contact }}"> <h4 style="color: rgb(200,200,200)"> {{ contact }} </h4> </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, in doing this the user is directed to

```
@app.route('contact_msg/<contact>')
def contact_msg_page( contact ):
    session['contact_clicked'] = contact
    return redirect( url_for( 'home' ) )
```

in Flask. Because contact is the argument in `def contact_msg_page`, a local variable in Python called contact is set to `{{ contact }}` (the link that the user clicked on). I then set a session variable called `contact_clicked`or`session['contact_clicked']` to be equal to the Python variable`contact`. Now that I've done that, I can access the session variable `contact_clicked` and do all the things I wanna do with it (e.g. when the user clicks on a contact in their contact list, it selects them to have a message sent to them by the user who clicked on them) <-- That's a mouthful.

I hope that this helps anyone who is having a similar problem to me. If anyone wants to ask any questions, ask away. I'd love to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the variable before the for loop:

```
randomStuff = int(0)

for i in range(0, 100):
   randomStuff += 1

print randomStuff
```

Hope this helps,

Jason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is referring to [Jinja2 template for loops](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-control-structures), not Python for loops. But we'll have to wait and see more of the code to be sure.

Comment: Sorry for not adding enough info, I meant  `{% for contact in contact_list %} <a href="/?{% contact_clicked = contact %}> {{ contact }} </a> {% endfor %}`

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I've added 'EDIT1'